# Display all product with same product code to ComboBox from MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have this table to my database

**tblProductsize**

```
ProductCode - ProductSize

  11111 - small         
  11111 - medium     
  22222 - large     
  22222 - medium   
  11111 - small   
  33333 - 2x7      
  33333 - 2x10
```

then to my form, it will ask to search the product code and I want to generate all those product size and display it into combobox that are equal of product code that been search...

I have table producttype in my MySql database and the Fields are the ProductCode,ProductName,Category.
This is my code of textbox to search the data from my table producttype in MySql database and display it automatically to the Product Code,ProductName,Category textboxes. The search is by ProductCode.
The name of textbox that we are going to input to search is TxtSearchCode.

```
Private Sub TxtSearchCode_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxtSearchCode.TextChanged
    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin;database=bsp"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim query As String

        query = String.Format("select * from bsp.producttype where ProductCode = '{0}'", TxtSearchCode.Text)

        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

        While READER.Read

            txtproductcode.Text = READER.GetString("ProductCode")
            txtproductname.Text = READER.GetString("ProductName")
            txtproductcategory.Text = READER.GetString("Category")

        End While

        MySqlConn.Close()


    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

And I want to generate also the size into my combobox from my table tblproductsize but it will display only the size that the ProductCode are equal of what we search above from the textbox. The fields of the tblproductsize are Id,ProductCode,ProductSize. The reason that I have this two table like producttype and tblproductsize is there are some productcode are same productname,category but different sizes.

And I come up to this code but it is not working.Yeah,Inside the TxtSearchCode handler I got this two connection two queries.

MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
  MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin;database=bsp"

```
    Dim READER1 As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim query As String
```

query = String.Format("select * from bsp.tblproductsize where ProductCode = '{0}'", TxtSearchCode.Text)

```
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConn)
        READER1 = COMMAND.ExecuteReader


        While READER1.Read

            Dim size As String
            size = READER1.GetString("ProductSize")
            cboproductsize.Items.Add(size)

        End While

        MySqlConn.Close()


    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And Lastly I want to save it also at two tables.

1. tblproductlist with the fields of ProductCode,ProductName,ProductPrice,SellingPrice,Category,Size,Quantity.
2. Tbldatestockin with the fields of Date,ProductCode,ProductName,ProductPrice,SellingPrice,Category,Size,Quantity_In.

And how I will save it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a simple query like

```
"select productSize from tblProductsize where ProductCode='YourProductCodeFromDropDown'"
```

Comment: In my form,actually the form is going to add products..and I am using two table..the tblcategory and tblproductsize.In the search textbox ,I get the information from tblcategory and display the fields of ProductCode,ProductName,Category and display it to their corresponding textboxes and I supply all of those remaining fields and one of the fields is the size that I should get it to the tblproductprice .One of the difficulties is how to set the query of getting the values from tblcategory and tblproductprice and display their corresponding fields according or equal to their both productcode...

Comment: Ajayr: one more thing uppon saving the it.I also two tables for saving the data, tblProduct and tbldatestockin.The fields for tblproducts are ProductCode,ProductName,ProductPrice,SellingPrice,Category,Size,Quantity. And in the tbldatestockin are Date,ProductCode,ProductName,ProductPrice,SellingPrice,Category,Size,QuantityIn. I do codes but I have error and my codes is look dirty..Help!